# How to convert from Color Wavelength to RGB or HSL?

Tags: fortran

I'm working on a project that part of it needs to translate from color wavelength to RGB/HSL/HSV (any of those), so I found this page: http://www.physics.sfasu.edu/astro/color/spectra.html and I kinda understand it but I need it as a Javascript function.

I've tried to do a simple scale between Hue value and wavelength, but it doesn't feel right. The thing is that the code that I found was made on Fortran:

RGB VALUES FOR VISIBLE WAVELENGTHS   by Dan Bruton (astro@tamu.edu)
This program can be found at 
http://www.physics.sfasu.edu/astro/color.html
and was last updated on February 20, 1996.
This program will create a ppm (portable pixmap) image of a spectrum.
The spectrum is generated using approximate RGB values for visible 
wavelengths between 380 nm and 780 nm.
NetPBM's ppmtogif can be used to convert the ppm image
to a gif.  The red, green and blue values (RGB) are
assumed to vary linearly with wavelength (for GAMMA=1).
NetPBM Software: ftp://ftp.cs.ubc.ca/ftp/archive/netpbm/

```
   IMPLICIT REAL*8 (a-h,o-z)
   REAL*8 CV(500,500,3)
```

IMAGE INFO - WIDTH, HEIGHT, DEPTH, GAMMA

```
   M=400
   N=50
   MAX=255
   GAMMA=.80
```

WRITE OUTPUT TO PPM FILE

```
       OPEN(UNIT=20,FILE='temp.ppm',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
       FORMAT(A10)
       WRITE(20,1) 'P3        ' 
       WRITE(20,1) '# temp.ppm'
       WRITE(20,*) M,N 
       WRITE(20,*) MAX 
       DO J=1,N
        DO I=1,M

   WAVELENGTH = WL

            WL = 380. + REAL(I * 400. / M)

            IF ((WL.GE.380.).AND.(WL.LE.440.)) THEN 
              R = -1.*(WL-440.)/(440.-380.)
              G = 0.
              B = 1.
            ENDIF
            IF ((WL.GE.440.).AND.(WL.LE.490.)) THEN
              R = 0.
              G = (WL-440.)/(490.-440.)
              B = 1.
            ENDIF
            IF ((WL.GE.490.).AND.(WL.LE.510.)) THEN 
              R = 0.
              G = 1.
              B = -1.*(WL-510.)/(510.-490.)
            ENDIF
            IF ((WL.GE.510.).AND.(WL.LE.580.)) THEN 
              R = (WL-510.)/(580.-510.)
              G = 1.
              B = 0.
            ENDIF
            IF ((WL.GE.580.).AND.(WL.LE.645.)) THEN
              R = 1.
              G = -1.*(WL-645.)/(645.-580.)
              B = 0.
            ENDIF
            IF ((WL.GE.645.).AND.(WL.LE.780.)) THEN
              R = 1.
              G = 0.
              B = 0.
            ENDIF
```

LET THE INTENSITY SSS FALL OFF NEAR THE VISION LIMITS

```
 IF (WL.GT.700.) THEN
    SSS=.3+.7* (780.-WL)/(780.-700.)
 ELSE IF (WL.LT.420.) THEN
    SSS=.3+.7*(WL-380.)/(420.-380.)
 ELSE
    SSS=1.
 ENDIF
```

GAMMA ADJUST AND WRITE IMAGE TO AN ARRAY

```
 CV(I,J,1)=(SSS*R)**GAMMA
 CV(I,J,2)=(SSS*G)**GAMMA
 CV(I,J,3)=(SSS*B)**GAMMA
ENDDO
ENDDO
```

WRITE IMAGE TO PPM FILE

```
       DO J=1,N
        DO I=1,M
           WL = 380. + REAL(I * 400. / M)        
           IR=INT(MAX*CV(I,J,1))
           IG=INT(MAX*CV(I,J,2))
           IB=INT(MAX*CV(I,J,3))

ITYPE=1 - PLAIN SPECTUM
ITYPE=2 - MARK SPECTRUM AT 100 nm INTEVALS
ITYPE=3 - HYDROGEN BALMER EMISSION SPECTRA
ITYPE=4 - HYDROGEN BALMER ABSORPTION SPECTRA

         ITYPE=4
         IF (ITYPE.EQ.2) THEN
            DO K=400,700,100
              IF ((ABS(INT(WL)-K).LT.1).AND.(J.LE.20)) THEN
               IR=MAX
               IG=MAX
               IB=MAX
              ENDIF
            ENDDO
         ELSEIF (ITYPE.EQ.3) THEN
            IF ((ABS(WL-656.).GT.1.).and.(ABS(WL-486.).GT.1.).and.
     *          (ABS(WL-433.).GT.1.).and.(ABS(WL-410.).GT.1.)
     *           .AND.(ABS(WL-396.).GT.1.)) THEN
              IR = 0
              IG = 0
              IB = 0
            ENDIF
         ELSEIF (ITYPE.EQ.4) THEN
            IF ((ABS(WL-656.).LT.1.1).or.(ABS(WL-486.).LT.1.1).or.
     *          (ABS(WL-433.).LT.1.1).or.(ABS(WL-410.).LT.1.1)
     *           .or.(ABS(WL-396.).LT.1.1)) THEN
              IR = 0
              IG = 0
              IB = 0
            ENDIF
         ENDIF

         WRITE(20,*) IR, IG, IB
        ENDDO
       ENDDO
       STOP
       END
```

Well, I've never even heard of Fortran code, so I don't know how it works. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Perhaps this document will help you implement it. https://aty.sdsu.edu/explain/optics/rendering.html

Comment: How is that related to javascript?

Comment: @Justinas oh, I forgot to mention that i need it on Javascript... anyways, thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save any future folks the trouble, here's the fortran code converted to javascript:

```
const wl2rgb_pregamma = wl => {
  if (wl >= 380 && wl < 440) {
    const s = wl < 420 ? 0.3 + (0.7 * (wl - 380.0)) / (420.0 - 380.0) : 1.0;
    return [(s * -1 * (wl - 440)) / (440 - 380), 0, s];
  }
  if (wl >= 440 && wl < 490) {
    return [0, (wl - 440) / (490 - 440), 1];
  }
  if (wl >= 490 && wl < 510) {
    return [0, 1, (-1 * (wl - 510)) / (510 - 490)];
  }
  if (wl >= 510 && wl < 580) {
    return [(wl - 510) / (580 - 510), 1.0, 0.0];
  }
  if (wl >= 580 && wl < 645) {
    return [1, (-1 * (wl - 645)) / (645 - 580), 0];
  }
  if (wl > 700) {
    return [0.3 + (0.7 * (780 - wl)) / (780 - 700), 0, 0];
  }
  return [1, 0, 0];
};
const wl2rgb = wl => {
  const gamma = 0.8;
  const [r, g, b] = wl2rgb_pregamma(wl);
  return [Math.pow(r, gamma), Math.pow(g, gamma), Math.pow(b, gamma)];
};
```

and to try it out on a canvas:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
for (var i = 380; i < 780; i++) {
  const [r,g,b] = wl2rgb(i);
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r*255}, ${g*255}, ${b*255})`;
  ctx.fillRect(i - 380, 0, 1, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is simple to read if you know that

```
.GT. = greater than
.GE. = greater than or equal to
.LT. = less than
.LE. = less than or equal to
1. = 1.000
1.1 = 1.1000
.1 = 0.1000
```

`1.1.GT.1` is same as `1.1 > 1`. Further

```
!this is a comment
IMPLICIT REAL*8 (a-h,o-z) !variables starting with a,b,...h and o,..,z are double scalars
REAL*8 CV(500,500,3) ! this is an array of doubles
```

Now you write the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

A wavelength can only be converted to a hue.

## Formula and Graph

The formula is (If *w* = *wavelength* and *h* = *hue*): ***h = (40/27)w*** or ***w = (27h)/40***.

 The graph is at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8unmqnujio (The hue is *x* and wavelength (in nm) is *y*.

Note that if the wavelength is less than 400 or greater than 650, you may need to add 360 to the hue until the wavelength is greater than 400 and less than 650.

## Code

### Hue to Wavelength

```
h = input('Hue: ');
def hw():
  w = 27 * int(h);
  w /= 40;
while w > 650 or w < 400:
  hw()
  print(w);
## Wavelength to Hue ##
w = input('Wavelength in nm: ')
h = 40 / 27
h *= w
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the CIECAM02 approach described on
https://www.magnetkern.de/spektrum.html, this MatLab inline function can be derived:

```
wavelength2hsv=@(x) [interp1([0 408 453 465 476 509 539 545 572 622 635 10000],[90 77 69 61 54 45 37 29 16 3 0 0]./100,x,'pchip','extrap'),ones(size(x)),(1-(abs(x-570)./200).^4).* ((abs(x-570)./200)<=1)];

wavelength2rgb=@(x) hsv2rgb(wavelength2hsv(x));
```

This can also be approximated without the need for interpolation:

```
wavelength2hsv=@(x) [0.9.*abs(((tanh(-(x-588)/130)+1)./2).^3), ones(size(x)), (1-(abs(x-570)./200).^4).* ((abs(x-570)./200)<=1)];
```